# calling js file in asp project

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have validation.js in scripts folder of my .net project. I am using asp:content pages which has master page. I have referenced the .js file in master page and used it in one of the asp:content web page but it does not work. I have also tried to reference it directly to the asp:content web page but it still does not work however when I copy the js code directly to the asp:content  page of header section it works. I have tried several things such as

```
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("../Scripts/js/validation.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have also tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/js/validation.js"></script>
```

What am I missing.

In my asp:content page I have textboxes such as

Please help me here

Comment: Try Remove the `../` and add `~/` i.e `<script src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/js/validation.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Why are you using 'Page.ResolveClientUrl' here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply drag the js file and drop it on master page it will automatically add js file with correct path.

Comment: Hmm I didn't know that nice !

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`ScriptManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) for referencing your `JS` file like

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="../Scripts/js/validation.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

If you want `JS` to be referenced in your Header section only you may use

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/js/validation.js") %>"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop the you JS file after the body closing tag :

Sample;

```
</body>
<script src="../Scripts/js/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!